# Is it possible to route different applications to different audio outputs with Pulse Audio?

Tags: linux, audio, gnome, pulse-audio

Is it possible to route different applications to different audio outputs with Pulse Audio? I'd like my music to be played on my Stereo, but I'd like sound alerts to be played on my notebook speakers. Is that possible with Pulseaudio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Ear Candy](https://edge.launchpad.net/earcandy). It is not only possible to switch between outputs when they're attached, but also to route several programs to other outputs as you're looking for (and lots of other small improvements).

Comment: Ear Candy is 6+ years old. Try `pavucontrol`, like mentioned below.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that's a built-in feature of PulseAudio. Various PA-compatible "volume mixers" such as `pavucontrol` or `ponymix` will let you assign a different output for each program (assuming PA actually recognizes those outputs as separate).

[image: pavucontrol]